# Digital Analog Converter chip , pre programmed?

Tags: arduino, dac

Is there a pre-programmed DAC chip?

I don't want to program any DAC, I would like to receive digitized voice data via a transceiver then feed it to a speaker/amp. The data is processed by Arduino Uno (8K Fs) then sent via a transceiver.

Trying to build something like a walkie talkie.

Comment: Many DACs require no programming at all, or if they are programmable they power-up with default values that could be useful in many situations.

Comment: @ThePhoton: can you give us an example of a DAC which requires programming? (That is the DAC itself, not some kind of embedded controller)

Comment: @Johan.A, To be honest, I was thinking more of ADCs than DACs when I wrote that comment. Nonetheless, the very first SPI DAC I investigated, (AD5412) has a programmable control register that allows adjusting output range, output slew rate, and some other features.

Answer (score 3):

DACs don't have code programmed in them, so a pre-programmed DAC doesn't exist. You supply a binary code to it, and the electronic circuit produces an analog voltage out. No software inside.

Comment: That isn't entirely true. There are CODECs (ADC/DAC, and probably my choice for the OPs application) out there that have almost as many control registers as a simple micro.

Comment: @MattYoung: While a CODEC may be an option for OP, he doesn't mention CODECs at all. He talks about DACs, and there are lots of DACs that fit his application and don't require programming at all.

Comment: In the end its voice that is transmitted as binary data . i'll check the links u gave me thanks alot. I'll come back if i have any questiosns

Comment: I just plug in the shield and it works ? no coding needed ? as i said i'll receive the data digitally via a transciever , then feed it into a DAC with 8K sampling rate... then aplify it and here it via a speaker 
@MattYoung

Comment: @gargoor: It would help if you told us the typenumber of the DAC. Normally you just start dumping data to it, but like Matt says, if it's a CODEC instead of a DAC some initialization may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the question again I'm starting to think you expect data going directly from your transceiver to your DAC, well, after you initialized the DAC.

That won't work. Your transceiver(*) outputs a serial stream of data, and your DAC needs more that 1 signal. If it's a serial DAC it will need data, clock and latch (or enable). If it's a parallel DAC you don't need the clock for the DAC, but you'll have to convert the serial stream to parallel in a shift register, and *that* will need a clock.
So you'll need some logic or software to split the datastream in data. clock and latch, but that doesn't have anything to do with programming the DAC.

Can you update the question with a block diagram of your complete system, and also add the type number for the DAC you're thinking of?

---

(*) Why is it a transceiver and not a receiver? Are you sending data back? Do you have a microcontroller at the receiver side?

Comment: Microphone + Amp --> ADC --> Transciever
Earphone + Amp <---- DAC ---< Transciever 

The ADC is within Arduino Uno . arduino uno also has a PWM i donno how to employ it as DAC yet thats why am asking about dac chip . i dont want to do any programming within out of scope of arduino right now due to shortness in time.
Send and receive voice as in walkie talkie . i might add a switch . Your msg complicated my mind upside downn .